# how to show difference between two Digraph using networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx

I have two Digraph

```
digraph G {
layout=dot;
ordering=in;
rankdir=LR;
"VOICE" [fillcolor=forestgreen, shape=box, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE" [fillcolor=yellow, label="VOICE", style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all " [fillcolor=lightblue, label="match-all ", shape=diamond, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___match access-group ipv4 VOICE" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="match access-group ipv4 VOICE", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___match dscp cs3" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="match dscp cs3", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___end-class-map" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="end-class-map", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE" -> "VOICE___VOICE";
"VOICE___VOICE" -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-all ";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___match access-group ipv4 VOICE";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___match dscp cs3";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-all " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-all ___end-class-map";
}

and 

digraph G {
layout=dot;
ordering=in;
rankdir=LR;
"VOICE" [fillcolor=forestgreen, shape=box, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE" [fillcolor=yellow, label="VOICE", style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any " [fillcolor=lightblue, label="match-any ", shape=diamond, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___match access-group ipv4 VOICE" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="match access-group ipv4 VOICE", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___match mpls experimental topmost 5" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="match mpls experimental topmost 5", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___end-class-map" [fillcolor=lightpink, label="end-class-map", shape=egg, style=filled];
"VOICE" -> "VOICE___VOICE";
"VOICE___VOICE" -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-any ";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___match access-group ipv4 VOICE";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___match mpls experimental topmost 5";
"VOICE___VOICE___match-any " -> "VOICE___VOICE___match-any ___end-class-map";
}
```

**Node can very in both**

we see there are difference in both.

How we can show difference like below or computing difference between two network graph with node and edges.
Order of text should maintain in compare section.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have add more input